# Messaging not working in Python firebase-admin

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to send notifications to topics in firebase using python. However, I am having a problem.

This is the error message:     `message = messaging.Message( NameError: name 'messaging' is not defined`

This is the code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials


cred = credentials.Certificate("path")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

topic = 'TestTopic'
def sendPush(title, msg):
    message = messaging.Message(
        data = {
            'title': 'TestTitle',
            'body': 'sometest',
        },
        topic=topic
    )

    response = messaging.send(message)


sendPush('hello', 'test')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank  you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you forgot to define this:

```
from firebase_admin import messaging
```